# Why is ggplot2 histogram behavior different when the x/y-axes have different types?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

[image]

[image]

The histogram on the top is a density histogram of the price and the histogram on the bottom is a density of carat(the diamonds data set).

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=price, fill=color)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..)) +
    theme(legend.position="none") +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())

ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat, fill=color)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Why different with above two pictures? How to do it? Thank you!

Comment: This is actually a legit question and should not be closed. See my answer.

Comment: I don't understand which difference is supposed to be relevant here, is it the values on the y-axis? @stata, can you try to explain further, and maybe try to upload better versions of the plot images?

Comment: Exporting the plots as two separate image files in png or jpeg format (pretty easy if you're using RStudio) should work better

Comment: @Marius I want to use above R code to plot the same above pictures, but now I can not.

Answer (score 1):

ggplot graphs try to behave intelligently depending on the type of the variables in the aesthetic (x,y,fill etc). But the default can't always get it right.

In this case, your x-axes have different types: ***price*** is an integer but ***carat*** is numeric.
If you want to override the default behavior, just use as.numeric/ as.integer/ as.factor/ etc. :

```
ggplot(... aes(x=as.numeric(price), ...
```

With price (integer), the default stat is stat="bin". So you get stacked histograms.

With carat (numeric), it's continuous. See the doc for details.

Comment: I can not plot the same pictures like above two pictures by using as.numeric/ as.integer/ as.factor/ etc. Thank you!